# Does .NET transliteration library exists?

Tags: .net, transliteration

Does .NET [Transliteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration) library exists ? Note that this is not translation, something like this Perl lib :

http://www.lingua-systems.com/transliteration/Lingua-Translit-Perl-module/

I just find :

http://transliterator.codeplex.com/

Comment: I have implemented it in asp.net c# using google Transliteration.

Comment: Google Transliteration lacks many european languages, for me is practicaly unusable

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check my **[UnidecodeSharpFork](https://bitbucket.org/DimaStefantsov/unidecodesharpfork)**.

It's based on great [Python Unidecode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) transliteration tables, support many languages.

Example usage:

```
Assert.AreEqual("CZSczs", "ČŽŠčžš".Unidecode());
Assert.AreEqual("Hello, World!", "Hello, World!".Unidecode());
Assert.AreEqual("Rabota s kirillitsey", "Работа с кириллицей".Unidecode());
```

Simple, fast and powerful. And it's easy to extend/modify transliteration table if you want to.

Comment: Ive been checking Georgian transliteration nad ქ will translate to k`, other sources will translate it to k (http://ge.translit.cc/, http://www.translitteration.com/transliteration/en/georgian/national/)

Comment: I am very satisfied with this library. Tested it with a number of languages, and the result is quite appealing. The only problem I encountered was with the transliteration of Japanese names: UnidecodeSharpFork read them as Chinese names, instead of Japanese: for "橋本" you get "Qiao Ben" instead of the expected "Hashimoto" (at least according to https://surnames.behindthename.com/names/usage/japanese, I myself do not know either language). Hiragana was processed correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not deliver any satisfactory results with Hebrew and, I suppose, Arabic. The problem is certainly, that of the vowels. In many cases, a transliterated Hebrew word contains gibberish like the '@' character; the Hebrew Vav is always transliterated as 'v' which is nonsense. I am still looking for a C# tool to satisfactorily transliterate Hebrew and Arabic into Latin script.