# transforming a hebrew word into english characters

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, ocr, hebrew

I need a java open source code that transforms a hebrew string into a string with english characters for example : transform the word "שלום" into "shalom"

Comment: Tag it with Java, so that the question reaches out to more ppl

Comment: Hebrew allows one letter to pronounce in several ways (w/o vowels) so this is really hard to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ICU transliterator.
http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general#TOC-Script-Transliteration

If that doesnt meet your need look around for Hebrew transliterator you will definitely find one.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could go is to use a Unicode transliterated font, but that would only work for display, that wouln't help if you really needed the "English", or "IPA" equivalent.

You could check out a transliteration library such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027001/does-net-transliteration-library-exists). 
CHEERS