# Convert special characters to normal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, character-encoding, special-characters

I need a way to convert special characters like this:

`Helloæ`

To normal characters. So this word would end up being `Helloae`. So far I have tried `HttpUtility.Decode`, or a method that would convert UTF8 to win1252, but nothing worked. Is there something simple and generic that would do this job?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I have tried implementing those two methods using posts here on OC. Here's the methods:

```
public static string ConvertUTF8ToWin1252(string _source)
{
    Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
    Encoding win1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

    byte[] input = _source.ToUTF8ByteArray();
    byte[] output = Encoding.Convert(utf8, win1252, input);

    return win1252.GetString(output);
}

// It should be noted that this method is expecting UTF-8 input only,
// so you probably should give it a more fitting name.
private static byte[] ToUTF8ByteArray(this string _str)
{
    Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    return encoding.GetBytes(_str);
}
```

But it did not worked. The string remains the same way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove diacritics (accents) from a string in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net)

Comment: probably just implement it yourself with a function with a switch inside

Comment: @James trying out the solution from the duplicate, will tell if it works.

Comment: @James The solution does not work for the string `Helloæ`.

Comment: Well, @James, I have tried implementing the method in the duplicate, and it does not work.

Comment: @HerveS fair enough. I can't revoke my close vote unfortunately, regardless, it is still a duplicate question. Did you try some of the other answers on the question? There were more ways than one to do it.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried two similar way posted in the question, but it does not work. Still looking for a way to do it, if you happen to know any, please feel free to offer.

Comment: Your comment "It should be noted that this method is expecting UTF-8 input only" does not apply since your function doesn't take a byte array but a String object as input. String objects are independent from any encoding. Once you converted a UTF8 byte array into a string, it will be same as any other string.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See: [Does .NET transliteration library exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027001/does-net-transliteration-library-exists)

[UnidecodeSharpFork](https://bitbucket.org/DimaStefantsov/unidecodesharpfork)

Usage:

```
var result = "Helloæ".Unidecode();
Console.WriteLine(result) // Prints Helloae
```

Comment: On my way to check UnidecodeSharpFork. That would be a good tool.

Comment: It's it's a compiled transliteration table based on other tables in Perl and Python.

Comment: This would seem to be the better solution, as it removes the burden of choosing what characters to transliterate to.

Comment: I'm not really sure about the license on this, so you might want to look into it before using.

Comment: Yes :) Exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct mapping between `æ` and `ae` they are completely different unicode code points. If you need to do this you'll most likely need to write a function that maps the offending code points to the strings that you desire.

Per the comments you may need to take a two stage approach to this:

1. Remove the diacritics and combining characters per the link to the possible duplicate
2. Map any characters left that are not combining to alternate strings

```
switch(badChar){
   case 'æ':
   return "ae";
   case 'ø':
   return "oe";
   // and so on
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that would be a solution. I must admit that I don't know how to do this. I'll update my post to show what I've done so far (which does not work).

Comment: `æ` is formed from the letters `ae`.

Comment: @James actually it's not, please look up the relevant Unicode, that is a distinct character U+00E6, as such there are no combining characters

Comment: I do not know how to do the second step. Can you guide me out?

Comment: Ok, I think I see your point, and comments mostly everywhere points to this solution. I think I'll implement something similar. I'll get you back if it works.

Comment: Using a switch like in this answer should be faster than the dictionary I suggested. At the end of the switch add default: return badChar;